# How to alter a button in cell on click in swift ios?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table layout inside a view which as a custom cell,The problem I'm facing is that the cells inside has a button i want to hide the button in cell on clicking it(only the one that is clicked should be hidden) how can i do thing in correct method?

**ScrollCell.swift**

```
class ScrollCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var ProfilePic: SpringImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var UserName: SpringButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var Closet: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Style: UILabel!
    //------//
    @IBOutlet weak var MianImg: UIImageView!
    //-------//
    @IBOutlet weak var ProductName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var LoveCount: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var Discount: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var OrginalPrice: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Unliked: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var Liked: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var Comment: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var Share: SpringButton!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        ProfilePic.layer.cornerRadius = ProfilePic.bounds.height / 2
        ProfilePic.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

**ScrollController.swift**

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1  // however many sections you need
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print(try! Realm().objects(Feed))
    var FeedModel = Feed()

    let realm = try! Realm()
    let tan = try! Realm().objects(Feed).sorted("ID", ascending: false)

    return tan.count // however many rows you need
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // get an instance of your cell
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ScrollCellDqueue", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ScrollCell
    IndexPath = indexPath.row
    var FeedModel = Feed()
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let tan = try! Realm().objects(Feed).sorted("ID", ascending: false)
    cell.ProfilePic.kf_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string:tan[indexPath.row].ProfilePic)!)
    cell.UserName.setTitle(tan[indexPath.row].FullName, forState: .Normal)
    cell.Style.text = tan[indexPath.row].StyleType

    if tan[indexPath.row].UserType == "store_front"{
        cell.Closet.text = "Store Front"
    }else if tan[indexPath.row].UserType == "normal"{
        cell.Closet.text = "Pri Loved"
    }

    //-----//

    var SingleImage:String = ""
    var ImageArray = tan[indexPath.row].ImageArraySet.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
    SingleImage = ImageArray[0]
    cell.MianImg.kf_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string:SingleImage)!)

    //-----//

    cell.ProductName.text = tan[indexPath.row].ItemName
    cell.OrginalPrice?.text = "\(tan[indexPath.row].OrginalPrice)"
    cell.LoveCount.setTitle("\(tan[indexPath.row].LikeCount)"+" Loves", forState: .Normal)
    cell.Discount.text = "\(tan[indexPath.row].Discount)"+" % off"

    if(tan[indexPath.row].LikeStatus){
        cell.Unliked.hidden = true
        cell.Liked.hidden = false
    }
    else if (!tan[indexPath.row].LikeStatus){
        cell.Unliked.hidden = false
        cell.Liked.hidden = true
    }
    cell.Unliked.tag = tan[indexPath.row].ID
    cell.Liked.tag = tan[indexPath.row].ID
    return cell

}

@IBAction func LikeBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
       print(sender.tag)
       print(IndexPath)
      //here i want to know who i can hide the button i have clicked ?
 }
```

Here i want to access the cell in which button is clicked and make changes to UI item inside that cell how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liked is uibutton in ScrollCell, i don't  known, why can you add IBAction for it in ScrollController? . You must implement it in ScrollCell And code:

```
@IBAction func LikeBtn(sender: UIButton) {
   print(sender.tag)
   sender.hiden = true
```

}

And i think, if you have only one UIbutton, it will better. In there, like and unlike is 2 state of uibutton(seleted and none). When you click the button, change it's state

Update:

```
    class sampleCell: UITableViewCell{
    @IBOutlet var btnLike : UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var btnUnLike : UIButton! // frame of 2 button is equal

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.btnUnLike.hidden = true
        // ...
    }

    func updateData(data:AnyObject){ // data's type is Feed
        // set data for cell 
        // i think you should implement in here. and in ScollController call : cell.updateData() , it's better

        /* e.x
        self.ProductName.text = tan[indexPath.row].ItemName
        self.OrginalPrice?.text = "\(tan[indexPath.row].OrginalPrice)"
        self.LoveCount.setTitle("\(tan[indexPath.row].LikeCount)"+" Loves", forState: .Normal)
        self.Discount.text = "\(tan[indexPath.row].Discount)"+" % off"

        */
    }

    @IBAction func likeTap(sender:UIButton){ // rememeber set outlet event for btnLike and btnUnLike is this function
        if sender == self.btnLike{
            self.btnLike.hidden = true
            self.btnUnLike.hidden = false
            // do s.t
        }else if sender == self.btnUnLike{
            self.btnLike.hidden = false
            self.btnUnLike.hidden = true
            // do s.t
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: here when i click the button i need to access the UI component (like button,label) of that cell and make change, Can you help me?

Comment: ya, i updated my post. In likeTap function you can access all public property of cell: label, imageview, button...  hope it's helpfull

Comment: Ya i saw now, Previously it didn't get loaded

Comment: It didn't work it changed data in different cell, not on the button clicked cell

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do it. One possible solution is use block.
Add this to ScrollCell

```
var didLikedTapped: (() -> Void)?
```

and receive the event of the LikedButton in the cell

```
@IBAction func LikeBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
   didLikedTapped?()
}
```

Then in cellForRowAtIndexPath of viewController add this

```
cell.didLikedTapped = {[weak self] in
    print(IndexPath)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if the following code help

```
   @IBAction func LikeBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
        var position: CGPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(position)
        let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)! as
        UITableViewCell
        print(indexPath?.row)
    }
```

Comment: it is swift function to get the relative position of the sender. It gives the coordinates of the button wrt the view

Comment: Thanks, Here i want to access the cell in which button is clicked and make changes to UI item inside that cell how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

give the LikeBtn the property indexpath,  in cellForRowAtIndexPath method, pass the indexPath to the LikeBtn, then you will know which cell's LikeBtn clicked.

```
class LikeBtn: UIButton {
    var indexPath: NSIndexPath?
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    // here pass the indexpath to your button
    cell.likeBtn.indexPath = indexPath


    return cell
}
 @IBAction func likeTap(sender: LikeBtn){ 
    if let indexPath = sender.indexPath {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
            //here you will know the exact cell, now you can hide or show your buttons
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give me an example please?

Comment: @Eathan Thanks i will try this